# blackberry mobile developement in windows Vista

Tags: mobile, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Can anyone please tell me if there is anyway to develop blackberry mobile apps in Windows Vista ? I need to develop apps for blackberry OS 7 & 6.
I have been trying to install the eclipse java plugin. It works fine windows XP and 7 but does not wok in Vista. Is there any other cross-platform tools avaibale to develop in Vista ?

Comment: Why do you specific need of vista.. Try by changing the compatibilty mode.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Download [BlackBerry JDE](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/jde) and install it.
2. [Download BlackBerry Ant Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net)
3. Download [Eclipse (without JDE plugin)](http://www.eclipse.org) or [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org) and install it.

Now use Apache Ant (comes with Eclipse/Netbeans),and [use BlackBerry Ant Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs).

In your build file, for ant tasks specify path to `rapc.exe` (compiler), `net_rim_api.lib` (main sdk library) and other JDE components required by a particular ant task.

And build your BlackBerry application file, sign it, package and launch it with the simulator. BB Ant Tools supports it.